# Alternate the default JTextPane font rendering

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane

Bro, considering the following simple html content.

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>.foot{color:red} .head{color:black}</style>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="xx" style="font-family:consolas">Hola!</span><br/>
    <span id="xk" style="font-family:tahoma">Hola!</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I have a swing application and I want to display the above code with a `JTextPane`, but I like to know how does `JTextPane` load up the `consolas` and `tahoma` font to print the `Hola` text data.
I'd like to override the default font rendering, the `courier new` font should be used instead of `consolas`, and `arial` for `tahoma`.
I don't like to replace the content and html content, I like to do it with `JTextPane` rendering method, maybe overriding something, IDK.
Now how may I get over it dude?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are looking for:
[JEditorPane#HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES (Java Platform SE 8)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES)

> Key for a client property used to indicate whether the default font
>   and foreground color from the component are used if a font or
>   foreground color is not specified in the styled text.

```
textPane.setFont(new Font("courier new", Font.PLAIN, 12));
textPane.putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, Boolean.TRUE);
```

**Edit**
You mean like this?

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public class IgnoreStyleTest {
  private static final String HTMLTEXT =
    "<html><head><style>.foot{color:red} .head{color:black}</style></head>"
    + "<span id='xx' style='font-family:consolas'>Hola! consolas</span><br/>"
    + "<span id='xk' style='font-family:tahoma'>Hola! tahoma</span>";
  private final JTextPane textPane1 = new JTextPane();
  private final JTextPane textPane2 = new JTextPane();
  private JComponent makeUI() {
    textPane1.setContentType("text/html");
    textPane1.setText(HTMLTEXT);

    //Font font = new Font("courier new", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    textPane2.setContentType("text/html");
    textPane2.setFont(new Font("courier new", Font.PLAIN, 32));
    textPane2.setDocument(new HTMLDocument() {
      @Override public Font getFont(AttributeSet attr) {
        StyleContext styles = (StyleContext) getAttributeContext();
        //return styles.getFont(attr);
        //return font;
        Font f = styles.getFont(attr);
        String ff = f.getFamily();
        System.out.println(ff);
        //if ("".equals(ff)) { //...
        return textPane2.getFont(); //Ignore: style font-family
      }
    });
    textPane2.setText(HTMLTEXT);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    p.add(new JScrollPane(textPane1));
    p.add(new JScrollPane(textPane2));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new IgnoreStyleTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but doesn't work bro for this case, I don't want to specify the default font, I would to replace styled elements(many). please help buddy :)